# Setting up Sharepoint 2010 - where to host AD?

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint

I am setting up Sharepoint 2010 Beta.

This is a development environment and via VMWare Workstation. I have a VM for SQL Server and another which will host Sharepoint itself.

With regards to AD, where should this fit in? Should I make another VM for AD or should I host it in the MOSS server?

I am using Windows Server 2008 x64 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a separate server/vm is always the better choice.  If your resource conscious go for a windows server 2008 core installation! & run it with minimal RAM.

Out of curiosity, if you have 2008 server why aren't you using hyper-v, which is free but using VMWare Workstation which costs $$

Comment: +1 for DC on a slim Core Server 2008 (or R2) (will take less than 5 GB of space and require ~256 MB of memory for a dev environment)...  and I'd love to plus it once more for the Hyper-V suggestion ^^

Comment: I spoke to a server guy at my work (senior windows server engineer) and he recommended I stayed away from Hyper-V. I can't remember his reasons why but I am sure from experience he has good reasons. Of course they may only apply to whatever he was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, in most environments Sharepoint will not be installed on a Domain Controller so my suggestion would be to create a new VM for AD.

Comment: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=112

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two separate VMs to create the farm, although you will still select the "Complete" option in the wizard when installing SharePoint. I'm right in the middle of doing the exact same thing with VMWare Workstation 7 and am going to post a blog here later today:

```
http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/11/21/Install-SharePoint-2010-on-Windows-2008.aspx
```

You don't need AD on a dev machine either. You can get around the "no local account" restriction with SharePoint 2010 by following these steps:

```
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/fromthefield/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=112
```

I'm using W2K8 Standard - as far as I can recall there is some new hotfix for R2, so check the team blog.

Some links for the DB part:

```
Script to open SQL Server ports:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/968872

SQL Server 2008 SP1:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=66AB3DBB-BF3E-4F46-9559-CCC6A4F9DC19&displaylang=en

CU2 for SP1: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/970315
```

**EDIT**

If the SP Pre-Requisites checker fails regarding Powershell, just install the latest 2.0 version manually:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=d37e25cf-db05-4b23-a852-cdf865d81b82&displaylang=en
```

**EDIT**

Fix for R2:

```
KB976462 would be the WCF Fix article for Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976462 (link not activated yet)

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=166231 (this is the download)
```

**EDIT**

```
http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/11/17/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2-and-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Part-4-Active-Directory-installation-and-configuration.aspx

http://andreasglaser.net/post/2009/11/17/Installing-SharePoint-Server-2010-on-Windows-Server-2008-R2-and-SQL-Server-2008-R2-Part-1-Overview.aspx
```

Comment: Yeah I've heard about the hotfix issue. I will wait for you to post your blog as it will help me :) However, I may in the future have seperate apps which require AD (eg MS CRM), so perhaps the seperate VM/AD approach will be good?

Comment: In that case I would definitely make my dev env as close a duplicate as possible of production.. I'm adding links to the answer above :-)